# Google Chrome freezes during fullscreen due to hardware acceleration on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, performance, hardware-acceleration

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 on Dell Vostro 3546.

```
uname -a

Linux vaishnavi-laptop 4.15.0-124-generic #127-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 6 10:54:43 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Whenever I turn on hardware acceleration in chrome for GMeet change background, I experince slowness only in Chrome, not in the system. To be specific, when I enter fullscreen either by <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> or by `double-click`/`"fullscreen"-button`, **Chrome gets stuck**. Only option is to restart chrome. When hardware acceleration is off, no problem, but I need it for GMeet.

- `chrome://gpu` when hardware acceleration is **off**:
  https://pastebin.com/vdTAEgUp
- `chrome://gpu` when hardware acceleration is **on**:
  https://pastebin.com/d7g6rpAD

Please help me !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I accidentally solved this problem by going to:

> Settings --> Devices --> Screen Display --> Resolution

and changed the resolution to the lowest, then changed it back to the highest.
I'm not 100% sure about this, but it worked for me.
I don't know how this worked, but anyway, now my issue is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue both on Windows and on Ubuntu. To clarify, it happed whenever chrome went full screen, and only occasionally when the laptop was unplugged, so I believe that the issue was with the discrete GPU.

**A recent driver update solved it.**

If it is not the case for you, I'd suggest Testing on the **latest Ubuntu** version.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm using Intel graphics, how to I update the drivers???

Comment: @GopalS I found this https://smallbusiness.chron.com/update-intel-drivers-ubuntu-42258.html

Answer (score -1):

This is a solution for the same problem except in Windows

Solution:

1. Go to settings/system/display/Graphics Settings
2. Choose the classic app option, and browse and select chrome.exe (should be in your chrome installation directory)
3. Press Options/High Performance
4. Enable Hardware Acceleration in chrome of course
5. Enjoy